# Java-version of Scala-placeholder

Tags: java

In Scala there is placeholder syntax `???` for code that you do not want to implement immediately. Is there something similar for Java?

I googled about this. Moreover, I tried to throw exceptions in order to achieve the same thing, but that is not what I actually want. I want a simple placeholder for code that I want to write later on.

Comment: You mean `// TODO`?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a utility class with this method:

```
public static void TODO() {
    throw new Error("not implemented yet");
}
```

and call that from the unimplemented spots. This throws an unchecked exception so that you don't have to declare it/handle it.

Comment: After defining TODO(), I wrote the following:


public Cell accessCell(int row, int column){
        TODO();
}


This gave me a "missing return statement" message. Do you know how I can avoid this?

Some context: I'm trying to write a simple tic-tac-toe game in order to get familiar with TDD practices and in order to prepare myself for the OCA 1 exam. The accessCell method is part of a Board-class.

Comment: @JanTinbergen1991 this does not save you from having to provide a return statement in methods. But `return null; //FIXME` is easy enough and should satisfy the compiler.

Comment: @JanTinbergen1991 but anyway, the actual standard practice for java is to just put a `//TODO` or `//FIXME` comment where you have something unimplemented, the IDE will collect those for you in one pile and let you find the next one to fix